# How to show hidden view with translateX in React Native

Tags: react-native

Here is the code:

```
<View
  style={{transform: [{translateX: this.state.translateX}], width: '120%'}}>
  <View style={{width: '20%'}}>{someText}</View>
  <View style={{width: '80%'}}>{someText}</View>
  <View style={{width: '20%'}}>{someText}</View>
</View>
```

`this.state.translateX` was respond to swipe gesture which worked fine, the first two View did move but the last View was not visible (or not moved?). I want to show the last View when `this.state.translateX` changed. But it seems not being properly rendered?

Answer (score 0):

It is because Android does not render element which is off screen. Solution is place the element in screen with `position: 'absolute'` and then use `translateX` to hide it from screen.